# Pixelated (not-smooth) curve in geom_function

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

How can I smoothen the chart line using ggplot2

I am trying to plot a graph for this function

```
exposure_funct_0.25 <- function(x) {
  exp(-0.25*x)
} 

exposure_funct_0.5 <- function(x) {
  exp(-0.5*x)
} 

 ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0,15)), aes(x=x)) + 
         geom_function( fun = exposure_funct_0.25, linetype = 2 )  + 
        geom_function(fun = exposure_funct_0.5, linetype = 1)
```

However, the code resulted in "broken lines" chart like this :

[image]

I tried to add `+geom_smooth()` but this one does not seem to work with my situation. Specifying n= 201 or higher does not help, unfortunately.

Is there any way to make the line smooth like this
[image: smoothened line]?

Comment: What do you mean by 'broken lines'?

Comment: You can increase the number of points to interpolate along the x axis. The default is 101, try `n = 201`.

Comment: are you referring to the pixelation/steps in the lower curve for x > 10?  It's going to depend a lot on the details (resolution, size etc.) of the image ... how did you save this image?  I'm having trouble reproducing this.

Comment: Hi Ben, yes I am referring to the pixelation/steps in the lower curve.

The issue is quite new to me and I do not know what caused it... How can I check the details you mentioned?

Comment: Hi Rui, I tried to increased the n but it does not work... I saw the quality of the image improved but the lags are still there.

I increased the n to 9999 but it does not result in the smooth line like I need

Comment: Could be an anti-aliasing issue (if you are using RStudio in windows for example, see [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4067)). I outputted the same image on my machine to png & pdf. The former has the same pixelated line as what you have here, while the latter is perfectly smooth.

Comment: Thank you Z.Lin. I tried to export as PDF and it is smooth.

I need to put the chart to a publication, so I will need to figure out how to do that then.

But at least now I have an option.